# Lambda pushing to SQS - Sync or Async

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have the following scenario:

Kinesis -> Lambda -> sqs

Everytime I receive a message from Kinesis, it triggers a lambda process which parses that message and send it to SQS where the order is important for that reason I'll have a FIFO queue.

For the lambda at first, I thought to implement a AmazonSQSAsyncClient but I think for this case it doesn't make sense (it should be the same to implement AmazonSQSClient) since I'll have 1 lambda process for each message. AmazonSQSAsyncClient would be useful with a process running permanentely.

I want to make sure that implements 
AmazonSQSAsyncClient or AmazonSQSClient is the same for this case. What do you think? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Could you please clarify: do you actually need to *implement* a client, or are you asking whether *using* an asynchronous or synchronous client will make a difference? If the latter, perhaps it would be helpful to re-word your question to have a punchline of something like "Am I right that my use-case is better suited to a synchronous client, and is there any better option I'm not considering, aside from using one client per lambda to parse my messages and send them to my SQS queue?" :)

Comment: Also: *"order is important"*: does this mean that you need your SQS queue to output objects in the same order as kinesis does? E.g. [A, B, C] -> Kinesis -> Lambda -> [A' B' C'] -> SQS -> [A' B' C']? Because if it does, then you can't easily have more than one lambda processing your kinesis stream. You'd need some way to guarantee the order invariant, or limit yourself to one lambda running at a time, since there's no guarantee that even lambdas started in the order you desire finish and push to the queue in the order you desire.

Comment: Actually, order is important for that reason I need a FIFO queue. I'm asking if using an asynchronous or synchronous client will make a difference? I think it doesn't but I want to make sure what you think. Also what should I do if I push a message and the queue is down, I mean is there something that I could check to know that? What it could be a good approach to handle this situation considering a FIFO queue? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, going off your clarifications in the comments:

> I'm asking if using an asynchronous or synchronous client will make a difference? I think it doesn't but I want to make sure what you think. Also what should I do if I push a message and the queue is down, I mean is there something that I could check to know that? What it could be a good approach to handle this situation considering a FIFO queue?

First, about ordering:

Assuming you **need** to maintain ordering starting at your Kinesis stream all the way through to your queue output, then you have two choices:

1. Let your lambdas run in parallel, and add a sort step in between your lambdas and the SQS queue. This will deal with the fact that if inputs `[A, B, C]` go to three different lambdas, they may return in some order `[C, A, B]`. I.e. there's no guarantee that they finish in the same order they picked the inputs up.
2. Never run more than one lambda at a time.

Which of the choices above is right for you depends on how much data is coming out of that Kinesis stream and how long it takes the Lambda to process it. If the answer is "not much" or "not long" then you could have just one Lambda process all the data (note you'll probably want it to be processing batches of data, not one datapoint at a time).

Next, **synchronous or asynchronous**:

If you only run one lambda at a time, then this boils down to "is waiting for the SQS put enough of a burden that it's worth it to do it asynchronously". If you run parallel lambdas with a sort step at the end, then the sort will be doing the putting. In either case, I would assume the answer is synchronous is simpler and therefore better, until you find otherwise.

Finally, SQS failures:

The general rule of thumb is that unless your uptime requirement is higher than the uptime guarantee of SQS, you shouldn't worry about it. [The SQS SLA is 99.9% monthly uptime](https://aws.amazon.com/messaging/sla/). If SQS is down, your lambda will fail. You should have a mechanism for handling failures in general (i.e. your lambda should retry failures, and log / alarm when it runs out of retries), but there's no need to write any logic to recover from SQS failures, because unless your system is doing something **extremely** critical it will be fine for it to be down as often as SQS is down.

Answer (score -1):

I do not understand your question concerning async vs. sync client but maybe the following article might help you with handling partial failures: https://read.acloud.guru/use-sns-to-retry-failed-kinesis-events-36e978782f05

Comment: Hey there - this article may contain helpful information, but links to non-SO sites can be unreliable. Best practice is to pull out a quote, see: *[How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."*

Comment: Thank you very much for this clarification. I should have read the guidelines before writing my anwser :(